# Resizing screen - Background image vanishing | Odd things |

Tags: html, css

If you look at my site everything seems to be ok, ... untill you minimize the website. A horizontal scrollbar appears and when you use that scrollbar, you will see that my image has vanished.

[My Website](http://www.md-esign.be)

I made that image responsive...so i have no idea why it is dissapearing...

I'm going to make the entire website responsive but i'm just doing it standard for now...kind of a trial. So i just want my bar to stay in the middle. I did this with the margin:0 auto...

When taking this out of my code it seems to be solved, yet i don't understand why this is obstructing my site...

```
.wrapper{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Show some code effort and ask specifically on it rather than asking someone to debug your site please.

Comment: There is NO doubt that you have done some effort but you don't show this here on your question. Based on the site rules, the community is willing to help on questions about programming but not questions of just figuring out problems generally without knowing what is going on on the code by guessing. Please, show your effort in code here if you want and ask on it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, your right. I found the reason why its happening...i just can't seem to understand why its happening. I'll edit my question

Comment: Happy to help if I can. Einstein would....

Comment: Pitty Einstein is dead right...I adjusted my question. Thx for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done on your navigation menu:

```
.navtop {
  width: 800px;

  /*Other rules*/
}
```

This will lead to a static width of your menu, even when resized, leading to a horizontal scrollbar. The image is white from there on, as it is resized to the size that the browser window has been resized.
I propose that you change that width to dynamic, using percentage, for example:

```
.navtop {
  width: 80%;

  /*Other rules*/
}
```

In general, avoid using static `width`s, as the site is developed to be responsive.
I also suggest that you look on some useful frameworks on responsive design: [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

Comment: If helpful, don't forget to upvote and/or choose this as best answer. Thanks!

Comment: You are very helpfull! Thx Einstein ;)! I would upvote your answer but apparently only people with rep 15 can vote. Democracy?!?!

Comment: Vote up require 15 reputation :(

Comment: Ok, you probably figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: I still don't understand why...how can you know what 80% is..every browser size is different. 80% of what? The browsersize? But that is variable... i'm confused.

Comment: It is the percentage of the current window size. For example, if you have a browser window set to 1024x768 pixels, then the width of the element will be set at 1024*80% = 819 pixels.

Comment: Ok, but lets say that someone uses 1280 as width on his browser window, than 1280*80% = 1024px. How can you code a website if you don't have fixed widths? I imagine not everything can be responsive...

Comment: Also, check http://www.md-esign.be I have the same issue again while i'm not doing crazy stuff. I know if i change the width to 90% it will be solved...but i don't want it to be responsive for now...If you resize the browser window a scrollbar will apear leaving white-space on the right...it bugs me a lot!

Comment: I pulling my hair out...i just want my content to be 960px and centered. Why is it doing that? Width: 960px  Margin: 0 auto;

Comment: Please be patient. Take one bug at a time. Also, use a code inspector in your browser (f.e. Firebug for Firefox). Check out if any CSS is conflicted (something that usually happens between different stylesheets on the same page) and that it works as intended and eventually you will figure it out.